# Memory Problem when using Itertools and product - Python (brute force script)

Tags: python, memory

I lost my password to open a locked rar archive. But I know the password approximately, so I want to try to brute force the password with specific characters. I found out I can use itertools and product and it works with small passwords, but the password I am trying to recover is 16 characters long and my script use more and more memory slowly (up to 10GB+) until I run out of memory and the script crashed.

I tried to use gc.enable() and del a variable to save memory but it doesn't seem to help much.
Hopefully one of you could figure it out.
Here's my code:

```
from unrar import rarfile
from itertools import product
import gc

gc.enable()
chars = '&yYvVtThH0#wW8jJlL'
num_char = 16

def findpassword():
    for p in product(chars, repeat=num_char):
        comb = (''.join(p))
        try:
            rarfile.RarFile('lockedfile.rar',pwd=comb).open
            break
        except:
            del comb
            continue
    with open("result.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(comb)
    print("Password found -> " + (''.join(p)) )   

findpassword()
```

Comment: Sounds like `rarfile.RarFile` might be leaking resources. You've got bigger problems, though. You're trying to brute-force your way through a search space of over a hundred billion billion possibilities, 18^16. Even if you could try one possibility per nanosecond, if you found the right password halfway through the search, it would still take you almost 2000 years.

Comment: Also, you never actually *call* `open`, and that blanket `except` is probably hiding bugs.

Comment: Use hashcat if you want to crack the password quickly on your own machine.